# 3 different types of JavaScript objects, what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I've been deep diving into JavaScript lately and stumbled upon a question.

What is the difference between the following implementations of a object:

```
var myFunction1 = (function myFunction1() {})();

var myFunction2 = {}

var myFunction3 = function myFunction3() {}
```

Or with a longer example of the three implementations preforming the exact same task.

```
<script>
    var myFunction1 = (function myFunction1() {

      var _privateVar = 'Private var';
      this.publicVar = 'Public var';

      function init( newPrivate, newPublic) {
        _privateVar = newPrivate;
        this.publicVar = newPublic;
      }

      function getPrivateVar(){
        return _privateVar;
      }

      function setPrivateVar(string){
        _privateVar = string;
      }

      return {
        init: init,
        getPrivateVar: getPrivateVar,
        setPrivateVar: setPrivateVar
      }

    })();

    var myFunction2 = {

      _privateVar: 'Private var',
      publicVar: 'Public var',

      init: function init( newPrivate, newPublic) {
        this._privateVar = newPrivate;
        this.publicVar = newPublic;
      },

      getPrivateVar: function getPrivateVar(){
        return this._privateVar;
      },

      setPrivateVar: function setPrivateVar(string){
        this._privateVar = string;
      }

    }

    var myFunction3 = function myFunction3() {

      var _privateVar = 'Private var';
      this.publicVar = 'Public var';

      function init( newPrivate, newPublic) {
        _privateVar = newPrivate;
        this.publicVar = newPublic;
      }

      function getPrivateVar(){
        return _privateVar;
      }

      function setPrivateVar(string){
        _privateVar = string;
      }

      return {
        init: init,
        getPrivateVar: getPrivateVar,
        setPrivateVar: setPrivateVar
      }

    }

    var a, b, c;
    a = myFunction1;
    a.init('Private var updated', 'Public var updated');
    console.log('== A ==');
    console.log(a.publicVar); // Public var updated
    console.log(a._privateVar); // undefined
    console.log(a.getPrivateVar()); // Private var updated
    a.setPrivateVar('Private var is updated again');
    console.log(a.getPrivateVar()); // Private var is updated again

    b = myFunction2;
    b.init('Private var updated', 'Public var updated');
    console.log('== B ==');
    console.log(b.publicVar); // Public var updated
    console.log(b._privateVar); // Private var updated
    console.log(b.getPrivateVar()); // Private var updated
    b.setPrivateVar('Private var is updated again');
    console.log(b.getPrivateVar()); // Private var is updated again

    c = new myFunction3();
    c.init('Private var updated', 'Public var updated');
    console.log('== C ==');
    console.log(c.publicVar); // Public var updated
    console.log(c._privateVar); // undefined
    console.log(c.getPrivateVar()); // Private var updated
    c.setPrivateVar('Private var is updated again');
    console.log(c.getPrivateVar()); // Private var is updated again
</script>
```

I know that the two first examples are singletons, and last one allows me to create multiple objects. But what are the difference between the first two? Or are they the same, just written a little different?

Comment: In your first example `var myFunction1 = (function myFunction1() {})();` doesn't give you an object. It stores the return value of the function into myFunction1.

Comment: @nderscore Yes, but isn't myFunction2 doing that exact same thing aswell?

Comment: No; myFunction2 is not a function.

Comment: The curly braces have different meaning depending upon how they're used. They can denote object literal syntax, or a block statement, or a function body.

Comment: ...they also have meaning within a regular expression.

Comment: If you were to put `new` before the short versions of `myFunction1` and `myFunction3`, then all three variables would result in an object being created.

Comment: JavaScript is a dynamic language without classes. So **every** object (or none, depending on your point of view) is a singleton, regardless of how it is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example creates a function `myFunction1()` and executes it, storing the result (not a function) in the variable `myFunction1` — in this case, the *name* `myFunction1` first contains a function, then (once it's executed) it contains the result.

`myFunction2` is not a function at all. The brackets `{}` are an object literal, creating an empty object.

`myFunction3` is the only function in the example. In this case it does nothing.

Comment: I was too slow in typing and the comments scooped me on half the answer. If anyone wants to improve this answer, have at it.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are using an IIFE ([immediately-invoked function expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) to keep private state.

You can't access _privateVar because variables declared inside an IIFE are in a closure.

Comment: You cannot access _privateVar declared inside myFunction2 either. But I get the fact that my second example isn’t a function at all. But what is the functional difference? It performs the same task?

Comment: @jamietelin : Hum no, I can confirm that you can access _privateVar in myFunction2. This is the functional difference

Comment: Have you copy / pasted and tested the code? I get undefined (updated my question with output)

Comment: @jamietelin : do `console.log(b._privateVar);` instead of `console.log(b.privateVar);` ;)

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH. Ofcource!

Comment: Updated question with my misspelling :-) Ty. And that explains alot, now I understand the scope better.